# iterm2: I maximize a pane and alt+tab to something else and when I return the pane is restored to its previous size

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I am using iterm2 with tmux integration and I have two problems.

1. I frequently have multiple panes in a single tab with one of the panes maximized. If I alt+tab out to, say, my browser, then when I come back to iTerm my maximized pane is automatically restored to its previous size. I find this behavior supremely annoying. How can I change it?
2. If I create a new tmux session, detach from it, and then reattach to it from a larger display, the iterm2 window will refuse to fill the whole screen. I can zoom in, but I would like to resize the tmux session itself while keeping the zoom level constant. How can I do this?

Comment: The vanilla terminal has this problems? Why aren't you using the vanilla terminal?

Comment: iterm2 has a lot of features that Terminal doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Agree this is annoying behaviour. I'm aware of two solutions (perhaps better described as workarounds) - either:

1) Enable Full Screen mode, or

2) Enable iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Tabs -> Show tab bar even when there is only one tab

Neither is perfect but there is no obvious way to avoid the resizing when the tab bar disappears.